Directory change tracking doesn't work for mapped network drives
The app tracks directory change which works fine for normal directories but for network mapped drives app gets event that directory has changed without any real change. That is happening just after starting tracking the drive.
BOOL bResult = ReadDirectoryChangesExW(pSettings->m_DirectoryHandle, &pSettings->m_dirChangedBuffer,
            sizeof(pSettings->m_dirChangedBuffer), pSettings->m_bIsRecursive,
            pSettings->m_dwNotifyFilter, NULL, &pSettings->m_overlapped, NULL,
            ReadDirectoryNotifyExtendedInformation);

//
if (!GetOverlappedResult(dirHandle, &(pSettings->m_overlapped), &bytesTransferred, TRUE))
{
    auto res = GetLastError();
    //assert(false);
    return {};
}

// here bytesTransferred is 0 for both normal and network drives
        DWORD dwDesiredAccess = FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY;
        DWORD dwSharedMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE;
        DWORD dwCreationDisposition = OPEN_EXISTING;
        DWORD dwFlags = FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;

        m_DirectoryHandle = CreateFileW(strRootFolderPath, dwDesiredAccess, dwSharedMode,
             NULL, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlags, NULL);

When app tries to track Z:\ or Z:\aaa it gets notification that directory has changed, but for normal directories event is emitted only when new file is created, deleted, renamed.
Do you encounter similar issue. Should I try using another API for tracking network mapped drives.
Update 1:
Actually GetOverlappedResult returns true and send real file change using transferred bytes but for network based drives it returns error 1  (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION)

Take a look at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110812-00/?p=9913

If the network redirector or the target file system does not support this operation, the function fails with ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION.
